# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and ZERO_RESULTS error when address passes from apex class

Tags: visualforce, javascript, google-map

I am passing an array of address from my apex class. The addresses are coming over fine in JavaScript but I get an error mentioned below.
The marker works fine when I hardcode the same address in the javascript.

> ZERO_RESULTS
>
> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Below is my VF PAGE

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="GetRoute">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps API v3 Directions Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAU45YYMFsnUGvJFTTcmxrP-dMTc3Eay9o&sensor=true"></script>


</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:repeat value="{!addressList}" var="a">
            The Text is {!a}
        </apex:repeat>
        <apex:inputhidden id="start" value="{!startpoint}" />
        <apex:inputhidden id="end" value="{!endpoint}" />
    </apex:form>

    <div style="width: 100%;" id="mapDiv">
        <div id="map" style="width: 70%; height: 600px; float: left;margin:0px;color:black;"></div>
        <div id="panel" style="width: 30%; float: left;margin:0px;"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myList = new Array();
    myList = '{!addressList}'; // When myList is used , error is thrown 
    var addressArray = ["Aurangabad","Kolkata","Lucknow"];   //This works fine
    console.log("========addressList======>" + addressArray);

    var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': myList[i]}, function(results, status) { // when I replace mylist with addressArray, I dont get any error
        console.log("=====City being processed====>"+addressArray[i]);
        console.log("=====STATUS=====>"+status);
        console.log("=====RESULTS=====>"+results);

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
        } else {
            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}



        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 0,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

        var request = {
            origin: document.getElementById("{!$Component.theForm.start}").value,
            destination: document.getElementById("{!$Component.theForm.end}").value,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                ex = document.getElementById("{!$Component.theForm.start}").value;
                console.log("====start point is ===>" + ex);
                console.log("=====ReSPONSE IS ======>" + response);
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Below is my APEX Class

```
public with sharing class GetRoute {
public static List<String> addressList{get;set;}

public GetRoute(){
    addressList = new List<String>();
    addressList.add('Pune');
    addressList.add('Indore');
    addressList.add('Lucknow');
    addressList.add('Delhi');
}
```

Below is a snapshot of the address in console. Seems same to me.
[image: Console log]

I am getting mixed result in console and the tags are showing in wrong country.
[image]

Comment: If you say it works when you hardcode the address on the JS, then probably there's an issue with your apex controller class. Post it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer that I came to what is the issue.Thought I was not not able to resolve it with the answer posted. I did some tweak i javascript as was able to get it resolved

```
var myList = '{!addressList}'; 
var a = myList.replace("[", "");
a = a.replace("]", "");
var array = a.split(",");
var addressArray = ["Pune", "Indore", "Lucknow", "Delhi"]; //This works fine
console.log(myList);
//debugger;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         //code pasted in question
}
```

**My List**

```
public GetRoute() {
        addressList = new List<String>();
        addressList.add('Patna');
        addressList.add('Indore');
        addressList.add('Lucknow');
        addressList.add('Mumbai');
        addressList.add('Bhopal');
        addressList.add('New York');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use `{!addressList}` in your Visualforce, what Salesforce returns to you as a string is `[Pune, Indore, Lucknow, Delhi]` (you can check this for yourself using `console.log('{!addressList}')`), and for you to use those values in JavaScript you'd need quote marks for those values, like `["Pune", "Indore", "Lucknow", "Delhi"]` (and it should be a list) otherwise JavaScript will treat each of them as variables (which are not defined in your code).

Secondly, in your JS you are passing `start` and `end` to the script that queries the addresses, but I don't see `startpoint` or `endpoint` in yoru class. So I think you didn't post the entire class code, or your Visualforce is invalid.

So I think your script is trying to query for `null` or `undefined` addresses, and it results in errors.

## To fix the variable to list

```
public with sharing class GetRoute {
    public String addressList{get;set;}

    public GetRoute() {
        List<String> addressList = new List<String>();
        addressList.add('Pune');
        addressList.add('Indore');
        addressList.add('Lucknow');
        addressList.add('Delhi');
        this.addressList = JSON.serialize(addressList);
    }
}
```

This outputs on the page and on `console.log`: `["Pune","Indore","Lucknow","Delhi"]`

Comment: Start point and end point i am passing form lightning component which is working fine on map. Shall i post that as well? How can i convert that in list.? Any idea about it?

Comment: Change your class variable from `List<String>` to just `String`, and serialize it to a JSON. On the page, it will be interpreted as a list.

Comment: I made suggested changes in Apex and i am still seing the same error. Do i need to change something in VF as well?

Comment: Forgot to add that I am getting mixed error in Console and the tag are coming up but on wrong location ..actually in wrong country. updated same in question